# how to show only particular class data on checkbox check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show full data intially and if the checkbox is checked, only particular class data should be show.
Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value = "seperate" id="seperate" onchange="return che()">

<table>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
</tr>
<tr class="one">
  <td>One</td>
  <td>One</td>
  <td>One</td>
<td>One</td><td>One</td>
</tr>

<tr class="two">
  <td>two</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>two</td><td>two</td><td>two</td>
</tr>
<tr class="one">
  <td>One</td>
  <td>One</td>
  <td>One</td><td>One</td><td>One</td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

here is my js code :

```
if($("#seperate").is(':checked')) {
    $("#one").show();

} else {
    $("#one").hide();

}
```

I want to show all data initially and on check it show show only 'one' class data.

Thanks For help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change` event on checkbox as follows,

```js
  $("#seperate").change(function() {
        //hide all tr with class name not equal to one when checkbox get checked and
        //show all tr when checkbox get unchecked 
        //you can use eq(0) or first to get the header row to avoid it from hidding on checkbox checking
        $('table tr:not(:eq(0),.one)').prop('hidden',this.checked);
        //or
        //$('table tr:not(:first,.one)').prop('hidden',this.checked);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="seperate" id="seperate">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>one</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="one">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="two">
        <td>two</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>two</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="one">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I Just updated My question and i added the table headers. The table headers should remain constant when check box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The Class selector is a dot(.) and not a hash(#). So the following code should work for you:

```
if($("#seperate").is(':checked')) {
    $(".one").show();

} else {
    $(".one").hide();

}
```

Comment: Note that this will only run on load, not when the checkbox is changed. The logic is also backwards; it only shows/hides the `.one` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that `one` is a class, so the correct selector is `.one`, not `#one`. Also your current logic is backwards as it only shows/hides the `.one` elements, instead of anything but the `.one` elements as the question describes.

To achieve what you require you could hide all `tr` elements which *do not* have the `.one` class. To do that you can use `:not` and `toggle()`, like this:

```js
$('#seperate').change(function() {
  $('table tr:not(:first, .one)').toggle(!this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="seperate" id="seperate" />


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>one</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan .. Working fine. But one more update. If want to show the  .two class data also on check what should i do.

Comment: How would that work? Do you mean you want to add another checkbox for the `.two` elements?

Comment: I want to show .one and .two on checkbox check. else it would show all the records

Comment: That makes no sense given the HTML sample you've shown above. I'd suggest starting a new question if you have additional changes you want to make

Comment: I Just updated My question and i added the table headers. The table headers should remain constant when check box is checked

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case add `:first` to the `:not` exclusion. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution**

```js
$("#seperate").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".one").hide();
  } else {
    $(".one").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="seperate" id="seperate">

<table>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="two">
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="one">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The logic here is backwards. Only the `.one` data should show on click. Also the first click does nothing. Also, please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.